# how to create phone number formating xxx-xxx-xxxx in monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to `xamarin` any one suggest me how to format a phone number in `xxx-xxx-xxxx` format. I have implemented the following `code snippet` in `textwatcher` but unable catch when user is pressing back button on keyboard.

```
 public PhoneNumberTextWatcher(activity context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {

            if (s.Length() == 3 || s.Length() == 7)
            {
                var phone = s.ToString() + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(45);
                context.Phone.Text = phone;
                context.Phone.SetSelection(s.Length()+1);
            }



    }   

    public void BeforeTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }

    public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression?

Comment: Yes, i also tried with regular expression

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, it seems you want to check if the number entered by the user was xxx-xxx-xxxx or not, that means '123-123-1234' is a valid number but '123-12' is not. Right?

Comment: Yes,exactly.I want to display "-" automatically when user enters the number.

Comment: Okay, you have to simply do this; firstly set the maxLength attribute of your EditText to 12. Then firstly remove any dashes in the string. Once the dashes are removed, check the length of the string, if it is 3 or more than 3 then insert a dash at the fourth position. Now check the length of the string again, if it is 7 or more than 7 insert a dash at the eighth position. This will work. I am on phone at the moment, else i would have provided you with the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.formatnumber.FormatNumber" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/formate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Formate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and Main.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FormatNumber extends Activity {

    Button btnFormate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_format_number);

        btnFormate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.formate);

        btnFormate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "formate : "+formatNumbersAsCode("1234567890"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private String formatNumbersAsCode(CharSequence s) {
        return String.format("%s-%s-%s",((String) s).substring(0,3),((String) s).substring(3,6),((String) s).substring(6));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public PhoneNumberTextWatcher(activity context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

int prevLeng;
boolean isBackPressed;

public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
{

        if(isBackPressed)
        {
            if (s.Length() == 4 || s.Length() == 8)
           {
            var phone = s.ToString().Substring(0,s.Length()-1);
            context.Phone.Text = phone;
            context.Phone.SetSelection(s.Length()-1);
           }
        }
        else if (s.Length() == 3 || s.Length() == 7)
        {
            var phone = s.ToString() + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(45);
            context.Phone.Text = phone;
            context.Phone.SetSelection(s.Length()+1);
        }
}   

public void BeforeTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
{
    prevLeng = s.Length();
}

public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    if(prevLeng > s.Length())
        isBackPressed = true;
    else
        isBackPressed = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally i got solution ....

 static int curserposition=0;
        bool backspace;
        string separator = char.ConvertFromUtf32(45);


        public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
        {
            if (s.Length() > curserposition)
            {
                if (s.Length() == 3 || s.Length() == 7)
                {
                    backspace = false;
                    var phone = s.ToString() + separator;
                    context.edit_Phone.Text = phone;
                    context.edit_Phone.SetSelection(s.Length() + 1);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (s.Length () != 0) {
                    backspace = true;
                }
            }
            if(backspace)
            {
                if (s.Length() > curserposition)
                {
                    if (s.Length() == 8)
                    {
                        string value=s.ToString().Replace("-", "");
                        var phone = value.ToString().Substring(0, 3) + separator + value.ToString().Substring(3, 3) + separator + value.ToString().Substring(6);
                        context.edit_Phone.Text = phone;
                        context.edit_Phone.SetSelection(s.Length() + 1);
                        backspace = false;
                    }
                    if(s.Length()==4)
                    {
                        string value = s.ToString().Replace("-", "");
                        var phone = value.ToString().Substring(0, 3) + separator + value.ToString().Substring(3);
                        context.edit_Phone.Text = phone;
                        context.edit_Phone.SetSelection(s.Length() + 1);
                        backspace = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            curserposition = s.Length();
        }   

        public void BeforeTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

        }
    }
```